# How can I configure AMD Radeon switchable graphics?

Tags: amd-radeon, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

I have a system with two GPUs, an Intel GPU and an AMD Radeon GPU.

The AMD Radeon software determines which GPU an application will use by default, and this is supposed to be configurable, but I'm having difficulty finding the right control panel.  The instructions I've found online don't work.  Where is the switchable graphics control panel really?

*I am looking for one or more canonical answers covering as many different versions of the software as possible.  I've posted my own answer (as community wiki) to get the ball rolling, but if you have any additional information please add it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on which version of the software is installed.

If you have a modern AMD Radeon with recent software, e.g., 18.2.1, you should right-click on the desktop and select AMD Radeon Settings, or launch AMD Settings from the Start Menu.  Select System (near top-right hand corner) and then select Switchable Graphics (also near the top-right hand corner).  [More details here.](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DH-017.aspx)

If you have a modern AMD Radeon with an older version of the software, you should right-click on the desktop and select AMD Radeon Settings, or launch AMD Settings from the Start Menu.  Select Preferences (near the bottom left-hand corner) and then Radeon Additional Settings (near the top left-hand corner).  This will open a new window.  On the left, expand the Power menu.

If you have an older AMD Radeon, you probably want to use the Catalyst Control Center.  There are various versions, so try the following:

- [As described here,](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2610379/switch-intel-graphics4000-amd-radeon-8570m.html) open the Catalyst Control Center from the Windows control panel, click Power and select Switchable Graphics.
- [As described here,](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3594040/amd-switchable-graphics-windows.html) open the Catalyst Control Center, select Manage 3D Settings, then select Program Settings.

---

*This is a community wiki answer; if you have found or written instructions for a version of the software not already covered, please add them, or post your own answer if you prefer.*